# Auto start nodejs app on Amazon AMI

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services

Any idea about the best way to auto start my node app on Amazon Linux AMI? I've seen a few articles on this, but not sure which is the most robust?

Jimi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use **User data** to do what you want, read http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html

Create new EC2 instance from the console as you'll do normally, when you get to **Configure Instance Details** page, you'll see a field **User data**, just enter a shell script to start your node application

You can review the output of the execution at `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log`